# CryptographicException in WCF with PushSharp

Tags: wcf, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp, cryptographicexception

I have a WCF service to send push notification to IOS device using APNS. I use the following code with using PushSharp.

I got an error at the "RegisterAppleService" step. The error explanation is:
**"CryptographicException was unhandled by user code
The parameter is incorrect."**

```
    private static PushBroker push;

    public string SendNotification()
    {
        push = new PushBroker();
        push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
        push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
        push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
        push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
        push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;
        push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
        push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;

        var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes("CERT_FILE_NAME.p12");
        push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "PASSWORD"));

        string devToken = "DEVICE_TOKEN";
        push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                                   .ForDeviceToken(devToken)
                                   .WithAlert("Hello World!")
                                   .WithBadge(7)
                                   .WithSound("sound.caf"));
```

I couldn't find the reason of the problem. How can I handle that exception?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you are using only the key generated with the signing request and not the certificate itself.

https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp

The steps are provided here, on step 18 be sure that you are exporting your certificate that is associated with the key and not just the key itself.

Also be sure that you are using development/sandbox ssl certificate for the development phase.